# Android Check If Sim is Locked

Tags: java, android

I have this running at the moment. It keeps outputting the value 5 which means SIM_READY

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int sim = telMgr.getSimState();
String sim2 =  Integer.toString(sim);
Log.d("SIM STATE", sim2);
```

I have run this on a few phones some that I know are locked and some that are not.

Is there something that I am missing as I thought this approach would output if the sim was locked by the network.

Cheers

Comment: Just to be sure, you are sure that the SIM cards on the other phones you've tried are network locked, not the phone itself?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I hadn't considered this. I am trying to do what I say, but if you could provide a way to find out if the phone itself is locked then I would accept that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way built-in to the android platform to do this. However, usually phones that aren't network-locked are rooted, and you could use [RootTools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/) to determine if this was the case.